# Why putting Peas in the Fish Tank to feed fishes clouds the fish water?

Tags: aquarium, freshwater, goldfish

I have a 30 gallon fish tank and the water was very crystal clean when I feed my fishes ONLY their fish flakes and pellets. As soon as I threw bunch of boiled, skinned, washed peas into my fish tank, the water got very cloudy within the next day.

Why would that be? It almost like the peas have oil on them.

Comment: maybe you should cut down the bunch of peas to a couple of peas and wait until your fish has eaten them before adding more peas,boiled peas is exellent food for bacteria and fungi because they contain sugars,proteins and carbohydrates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I routinely feed peas (green) and corn to Koi in a pond; I just take some from the frozen food bag and toss them in the pond. The Giant Danios apparently eat them also. The primary cause of cloudy aquarium water is overfeeding, that is what I would check first.